# Function bijective proving.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Let $\mathbb{C}$ be the set of all complex number. $z\in \mathbb{C}$

Given a function $$ f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} $$

$$f(z) = (1+2i)z+5i$$

Prove that it is bijective.

First, prove injective
$\forall z_1\forall z_2, f(z_1)=f(z_2) \implies z_1 = z_2 $

$f(z_1) = (1+2i)z_1+5i$ = $f(z_2) = (1+2i)z_2+5i$

Thus as needed $ z_1 = z_2$ Am I correct?

How do I prove it is surjective

Comment: @vadim123. Edited. It was meant to be $i$

Answer (score 1):

You know that, in $\mathbb{C}$, if $xy=0$, then either $x=0$ or $y=0$.

So, from $f(z_1)=f(z_2)$ you get
$$
(1+2i)z_1+5i=(1+2i)z_2+5i
$$
that becomes
$$
(1+2i)z_1=(1+2i)z_2
$$
or
$$
(1+2i)(z_1-z_2)=0
$$
Therefore…

For surjectivity, are you able to solve the equation
$$
w=(1+2i)z+5i
$$
with respect to $z$, where $w$ is any complex number?

Answer (score 0):

Write $z=a+bi, a,b\in \mathbb{R}$

$f(z_1) =f(z_2)\iff (1+2i)z_1+5i= (1+2i)z_2+5i$

$\iff (a_1-2b_1)+(2a_1+b_1+5)i=(a_2-2b_2)+(2a_2+b_2+5)i $

Clearly $a_1=a_2,b_1=b_2$ since the linear equations are linearly independent.

$f(z)=(a-2b)+(2a+b+5)i=x+yi$, given $x,y$ you can solve for $a,b$, so $f$'s surjective.